# How to add Where Conditions in LINQ Joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and ASPNet Core 1.1.

I am trying to get the list of manufacturers and the count of assets attached to that.

```
Assets.ManufacturerID -> Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
```

The following query works fine and it almost gives me the result I want.

```
var result = (from m in _context.Manufacturers
                join a in _context.Assets                         
                on m.ManufacturerID.ToString() equals a.ManufacturerID                                                   
                into joined
                where m.status == 0
                select new AssetsDB.ViewModels.ManufacturerIndexViewModel()
                {
                    ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID,
                    Description = m.Description,
                    Count = joined.Count()
                });
```

However, I just want to introduce additional where statements to filter the state of the Assets.

I tried to use the following after join & on statement, but it doesn't work and keep saying 'a' does not exist in the current context

```
where a.state == 0
where m.status == 0 && a.state == 0
```

Could you please give me an advise how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter the  `Assets`collection before apply `join`:

```
var result = (  from m in _context.Manufacturers
                join a in _context.Assets.Where(a=>a.state==0) //Add this                       
                on m.ManufacturerID equals a.ManufacturerID into joined
                where m.status == 0
                select new AssetsDB.ViewModels.ManufacturerIndexViewModel()
                {
                    ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID,
                    Description = m.Description,
                    Count = joined.Count()
                });
```

The thing is you are doing a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx) where the result selector has access to every element of the first collection, but not to the elements of the second one individually. In other words for each entity of the first collection the correlated entities of the second collection will be grouped into the `joined` collection, and that is what you have access in the result selector.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Lambda way

```
var result = _context.Manufacturers
   .Where(m => m.status == 0)
   .Join(_context.Assets.Where(a => a.state == 0), 
         a => a.ManufacturerID,
         m => m.ManufacturerID.ToString(),
        (a,m) => new AssetsDB.ViewModels.ManufacturerIndexViewModel
                 {
                         ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID,
                         Description = m.Description,
                         Count = m.Count()
                 }
   )
   .ToList();
```